# Split string into associative array (while maintaining characters)

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to split a string that looks like this :

`a20r51fx500fy3000`

into an associative array that will look like this :

```
array(
    'a' => 20,
    'r' => 51,
    'fx' => 500,
    'fy' => 3000,
);
```

I don't think I can use preg_split as this will drop the character I'm splitting on (I tried `/[a-zA-Z]/` but obviously that didn't do what I wanted it to). I'd prefer if I could do it using some kind of built-in function, but I don't really mind looping if that's required.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `preg_match_all('/([a-z]+)(\d+)/', ...` should get you most of the way there. Then do a little loop to format the array the way you want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Multiple Matches and PREG_SET_ORDER

Do this:

```
$yourstring = "a20r51fx500fy3000";
$regex = '~([a-z]+)(\d+)~';
preg_match_all($regex,$yourstring,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
$yourarray=array();
foreach($matches as $m) {
    $yourarray[$m[1]] = $m[2];
}
print_r($yourarray);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [a] => 20 [r] => 51 [fx] => 500 [fy] => 3000 )
```

If your string can contain upper-case letters, make the regex case-insensitive by adding the `i` flag after the closing delimiter: `$regex = '~([a-z]+)(\d+)~i';`

**Explanation**

- `([a-z]+)` captures letters to Group 1
- `(\d+)` captures digits to Group 1
- `$yourarray[$m[1]] = $m[2];` creates in index for the letters, and assigns the digits

Comment: Also note that if your string can contain upper-case letters, just make the regex case-insensitive with the `i` flag: `$regex = '~([a-z]+)(\d+)~i';`

Comment: Why you used `PREG_SET_ORDER`?

Comment: you can read this on php.net

PREG_SET_ORDER
Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern, and so on.